# MySQL - Count of consecutive occurrences

Tags: mysql

With respect to [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75c3aa/1),

```
create table tbl(`date` date, customer varchar(200), 
                  serv_info varchar(200), category varchar(20));

insert into tbl values
('2015-01-01', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-02', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-03', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-11', 'customerA', 'Type1Id2', 'AG'),
('2015-01-13', 'customerA', 'Type1Id2', 'AG'),
('2015-01-16', 'customerA', 'Type1Id3', 'AG'),
('2015-01-20', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-21', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-22', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-23', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-11', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-12', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-13', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG');
```

I'd like to see the below output -

```
10/01/15 - Type1Id1 -10
11/01/15 - Type1Id2 - 5
16/01/15 - Type1Id1 -3
```

I've managed to do the categorization with the SQL, however, I'm not able to fully achieve the requirement specially the consecutive count for the same server ID of a given type at various points in time. (I'm not a full fledged MYSQL person & hence struggling to get this right)

Could I please request help to get this working fully. I've tried my best toe explain the scenario. if it's unclear, please do let me know what is unclear & I'll try to restate it.

Comment: We need sample data and desire result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. Also Try create a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Right now your picture doesnt match your sample. And text sample are always better because we cant copy / paste from pictures

Comment: Sure - no problem. I'll update that.

Comment: Also check your sample, you say type1 assigned for 10 day and type2 for 5 days, where you get that information

Comment: The count of 10,5 etc is the count of (SERV_INFO) when counted everyday until the consecutive occurrence breaks. If there is an entry int he database everyday for 10 continuous days, then the count = 10 for that server ID & so forth.

Comment: As I said you need provide a better sample.

Comment: Sure, preparing that. I'll update a fiddle link once ready. Thank you very much

Comment: I've created a fiddle further to the answer below. I've updated it with the details crated by the user below to continue debugging. Have updated the question with the link.

Comment: You should always include the relevant data, because sometime sqlFiddle is down.

Comment: Also you have to explain the logic. I dont see where you get `10/01/15 Type1` and how is that `10` or why isnt `Type1Id3` present or `Type2Id1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on aggregate function, group by and User variable. User variable is used here to guarantee the consequence.

The output is also slightly formatted to match the requirement.

SQL:

```
-- Data preparation
create table tbl(`date` date, customer varchar(200), serv_info varchar(200), category varchar(20));
insert into tbl values
('2015-01-01', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-02', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-03', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-11', 'customerA', 'Type1Id2', 'AG'),
('2015-01-13', 'customerA', 'Type1Id2', 'AG'),
('2015-01-16', 'customerA', 'Type1Id3', 'AG'),
('2015-01-20', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-21', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-22', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-23', 'customerA', 'Type2Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-11', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'), 
('2015-01-12', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'), 
('2015-01-13', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG');
SELECT * FROM tbl;

-- Needed
SET @rownum = 0;
SET @typeid = '';
SELECT 
    CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(assign_date, '%d/%m/%y'), ' - ', tbl2.serv_info, ' - ', tbl2.consecutive_days ) Output
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(`date`) assign_date, 
        serv_info, 
        COUNT(1) consecutive_days,
        @rownum:=@rownum+(serv_info != @typeid) conse_group,
        @typeid:=serv_info
    FROM tbl
    WHERE customer = 'customerA'
    GROUP BY conse_group) tbl2;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl;
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| date       | customer  | serv_info | category |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 2015-01-01 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-02 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-03 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-11 | customerA | Type1Id2  | AG       |
| 2015-01-13 | customerA | Type1Id2  | AG       |
| 2015-01-16 | customerA | Type1Id3  | AG       |
| 2015-01-20 | customerA | Type2Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-21 | customerA | Type2Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-22 | customerA | Type2Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-23 | customerA | Type2Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-11 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-12 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
| 2015-01-13 | customerA | Type1Id1  | AG       |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Needed
mysql> SET @rownum = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @typeid = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(assign_date, '%d/%m/%y'), ' - ', tbl2.serv_info, ' - ', tbl2.consecutive_days ) Output
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT
    ->     MIN(`date`) assign_date,
    ->     serv_info,
    ->     COUNT(1) consecutive_days,
    ->     @rownum:=@rownum+(serv_info != @typeid) conse_group,
    ->     @typeid:=serv_info
bl2;
    ->     FROM tbl
    ->     WHERE customer = 'customerA'
    ->     GROUP BY conse_group) tbl2;
+-------------------------+
| Output                  |
+-------------------------+
| 01/01/15 - Type1Id1 - 3 |
| 11/01/15 - Type1Id2 - 2 |
| 16/01/15 - Type1Id3 - 1 |
| 20/01/15 - Type2Id1 - 4 |
| 11/01/15 - Type1Id1 - 3 |
+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan. The query I was trying was heaps complicated :)

Comment: Hello Dylan - I added `Type1id1` again towards the end as follows `('2015-01-11', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-12', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG'),
('2015-01-13', 'customerA', 'Type1Id1', 'AG');
` In this case, the query above shows a total consecutive days of 6 starting from `2015-01-01` instead of showing 3 each starting from `2015-01-01` & `2015-01-11`.  I'm in need to see this as mentioned in the question - `10/01/15 - Type1Id1 -10
11/01/15 - Type1Id2 - 5
16/01/15 - Type1Id1 -3`

Comment: Do you expect Type1id1 to have two rows in the output in  this case?

Comment: Yes please. I'd like show as many consecutive occurrences as are present in their own bunch. I mean to say,for example,  if there are 10 pairs of consecutive occurrences with each consecutive period of 3 days , I would like to see 10 entries for `TypeId1` with the start date being whenever the consecutive period started

Comment: I get it. That will be much more complicated.

Comment: @usert4jju7 Provide with a new solution, adding usage of user variable. My ans is updated. Pls check if this is what you want.

Comment: Hello Dylan - Very much appreciate your help here. Woks like a charm. If I may add just one more thing, I tried removing duplicate entries in the output by using `DELETE bla bla ` & `NOT IN` conditions but can't get it to work as I don't fully understand the complex query you've written. Could you please help me add just this one filter?

Comment: @usert4jju7 didn't get what you want this time. can u give some example?

Comment: what kind of dup do you mean?

Comment: Two identical rows of data - where 2 rows have same values for  `date`, `customer`, `serv_info` & `category`

Comment: the removal will also -1 in the count.  do you accept that?

Comment: yeah that's actually the right result. Duplicates shouldn't be counted

Comment: @usert4jju7 does ur table has a primary key? What kind of order does ur  original table takes?

Comment: I tried, but didn't find a solution to remove the duplicate.

Comment: No problem Dylan. Thank you heaps.